# How to sort a string without using sort function or array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, integer

I want to sort 2 numbers from greatest to least without using a sort function or an array. Eg. input 4 and 8 and output will be 84, I don't want any commas or spaces in between the numbers. Written in Python 3 please.

Comment: Just two numbers? With no sorting. Can you use `if`? `<`?

Comment: The question title asks about sorting strings, and the text asks about sorting numbers? Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Given two numbers, from somewhere, `x` and `y`

```
print(str(max(10*x + y, x + 10*y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Feeding off of Shawn Steffey, add the int(input()) to make sure input request is in an integer, in the if statement you take the two ints, make them a string, add them together and it will print "ab" or "ba" depending on input.

```
a = int(input("Enter a number"))

b = int(input("Enter a number"))

if a >= b:
    print(str(a) + str(b))
else:
    print(str(b) + str(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds homeworky, based on the requirements.

If it is always two numbers being "sorted", try writing a basic comparison function.

eg. (in pseudocode, not specifically Python):

```
if(a >= b)
  print(a + b);
else
  print(b + a);
```

Comment: 8 + 4 = 84??  :)

Comment: Haha, woops.  Sorry,  getting too string excited.  Treat that as a dot separator or whatever language-specific way to make that concat two strings.
`print(a + "" + b)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) like this:

```
a = 4
b = 8
res = '{}{}'.format(max(a, b), min(a, b))
print(res)  # Output: '84'
```